# How to change duplicated names in many columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
CODIGO NOMBRE           Enero  Enero  Febrero  Febrero  Marzo  Marzo  ....                                        
000130 RICA PLAYA       31.3   21.0     31.7     22.0   31.8   22.0
000132 PUERTO PIZARRO   32.5   19.0     32.2     18.0   32.5   17.0
000134 PAPAYAL          31.7   25.0     31.5     27.0   31.8   26.0
000135 EL SALTO         31.1   27.0     31.5     26.0   31.5   26.0
000136 CAÑAVERAL        32.4   17.0     32.0     16.0   32.3   16.0
                     ...    ...      ...      ...    ...    ...
158317 SUSAPAYA         17.3   20.0     16.8     20.0   17.2   19.0
158321 PALCA            17.9   16.0     17.8     17.0   18.4   16.0
158323 TALABAYA         17.1   12.0     16.7     12.0   17.2   12.0
158326 CAPAZO           13.7   19.0     13.6     19.0   13.5   17.0
158328 PAUCARANI        13.1   15.0     12.9     15.0   13.4   14.0  ....
```

with 26 columns.

I want to rename the second Enero to N1, and the second Febrero to N2, second Marzo to N3, etc etc like this:

```
CODIGO NOMBRE           Enero  N1      Febrero   N2     Marzo  N3   ....                                        
000130 RICA PLAYA       31.3   21.0     31.7     22.0   31.8   22.0
000132 PUERTO PIZARRO   32.5   19.0     32.2     18.0   32.5   17.0
000134 PAPAYAL          31.7   25.0     31.5     27.0   31.8   26.0
000135 EL SALTO         31.1   27.0     31.5     26.0   31.5   26.0
000136 CAÑAVERAL        32.4   17.0     32.0     16.0   32.3   16.0
                     ...    ...      ...      ...    ...    ...
158317 SUSAPAYA         17.3   20.0     16.8     20.0   17.2   19.0
158321 PALCA            17.9   16.0     17.8     17.0   18.4   16.0
158323 TALABAYA         17.1   12.0     16.7     12.0   17.2   12.0
158326 CAPAZO           13.7   19.0     13.6     19.0   13.5   17.0
158328 PAUCARANI        13.1   15.0     12.9     15.0   13.4   14.0  ....
```

So I did:

```
df.columns['CODIGO','NOMBRE','Enero','N1','Febrero','N2'...... etc etc]
```

Is there a more efficient or faster way to do this than writing every name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming duplicated values are in the correct order they can be replaced by modifying the [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.values.html) of [`columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) where [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html):

```
m = df.columns.duplicated()
df.columns.values[m] = [f'N{i}' for i in range(1, 1 + m.sum())]
```

Or with [`arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and `Series`:

```
import numpy as np

df.columns.values[m] = 'N' + pd.Series(np.arange(1, 1 + m.sum()), dtype=str)
```

Or with [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df.columns.values[m] = 'N' + pd.Series(m.cumsum()[m], dtype=str)
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['CODIGO', 'NOMBRE', 'Enero', 'Enero',
                           'Febrero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Marzo'])
print('Before', df)

m = df.columns.duplicated()
df.columns.values[m] = [f'N{i}' for i in range(1, 1 + m.sum())]

print('After', df)
```

```
Before Empty DataFrame
Columns: [CODIGO, NOMBRE, Enero, Enero, Febrero, Febrero, Marzo, Marzo]
Index: []

After Empty DataFrame
Columns: [CODIGO, NOMBRE, Enero, N1, Febrero, N2, Marzo, N3]
Index: []
```